Is there a way to pass synonyms specific to a single document
I want to set synonyms specific to a document being indexed, but neither synonym file nor synonym set (which are options that can be reloaded), can be used in the indexing (only as search filters).
Is there a way to create a synonym, or multiplexer filter, that will create two tokens for the same position based on some dynamic condition provided either through analyzer update, or script option in some filter that will use document fields to emit tokens at specific position?
Graph example:
0 - documentSpecificTokenA - 1
0 - documentSpecificTokenB - 1


Maybe this answer helps you

@G0l0s No good, that answer isn't using dynamically provided context. I'll try to get my thing to work with pattern replace token filter because regex might be all the logic I need.

Dear @Desperado, maybe you provide 'some dynamic condition'?

That will be easy since conditional filter can be scripted, but the mapping/emitting of tokens is not dynamic (besides closing and opening index after updating mappings_path of Mapping character filter)
